# Couchbase Lite Replication setFilter and setFilterParams

Tags: database-replication, couchbase-lite

From the [couchbase docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html), I see that I can set a push filter and filter parameters. However, it is not clear to me how this work when a filter changes.  For example, suppose I do the following:

```
push.setFilter("byOwner");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("name", "Waldo");
push.setFilterParams(params);
```

where `byOwner` only allows documents through owned by `name`, so in this case `Waldo`.  Several documents belonging to `Waldo` change over time, as do documents belonging to a user `Foo`, but only `Waldo`'s make it through the replication.  Then, a few minutes later, I do:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("name", "Foo");
push.setFilterParams(params);
```

Will the push replication now push all changed documents owned by `Foo` to the server?  Or will it only pick up new changes (meaning those after `params` is reset) and send them to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It will push all documents owned by `Foo` (and if it doesn't then file a bug report).